# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer::ErrorInfo() in /home/maised/public_html/cv/index.php on line 189

Tags: php, phpmailer

I tried everything and now I don't know why I'm getting this error. I watched a video while writing this. And I think I'm using the newer version of the PHPMailer. And the video uploaded at 2014... Please help me about that. I need to fix this quickly.

Here is my error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer::ErrorInfo() in /home/maised/public_html/cv/index.php on line 189
```

Here is the code:

```
if($_POST){

$AdSoyad=$POST['AdSoyad'];
$Cinsiyet=$POST['Cinsiyet'];
$adres=$POST['adres'];
$telefon=$POST['telefon'];
$dogumtarih=$POST['dogumtarih'];
$EPosta=$POST['EPosta'];
$egitim=$POST['egitim'];
$Medeni=$POST['Medeni'];
$tecrubeyil=$POST['tecrubeyil'];
$asker=$POST['asker'];
$meslekitecrube=$POST['meslekitecrube'];
$ybncdil=$POST['ybncdil'];
$blgsyrblg=$POST['blgsyrblg'];
$meslekitecrube=$POST['meslekitecrube'];


$klasor="uploads";
$sayi=time().rand();
$uzanti=explode(".",$_FILES['cvresim']['name']);
$uzanti=end($uzanti);
$adi=$sayi.'.'.$uzanti;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['cvresim']['tmp_name'],$klasor.'/'.$adi);

require('PHPMailer.php');
require('SMTP.php');
require('bilgiler.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet="UTF-8";

$body="Ad Soyad: {$AdSoyad}<br>Cinsiyet: {$Cinsiyet}<br>Adres: {$adres}<br>Telefon No: {$telefon}<br>Doğum Tarihi: {$dogumtarih}<br>E-Posta: {$EPosta}<br>Eğitim Durumu: {$egitim}<br>Medeni Durum:{$Medeni}<br>Tecrübe(Yıl): {$tecrubeyil}<br>Askerlik Durumu: {$asker}<br>Mesleki Tecrübe: {$meslekitecrube}<br>Yabancı Dil: {$ybncdil}<br>Bilgisayar Bilgisi: {$blgsyrblg}<br>Mesleki Tecrübe: {$meslekitecrube}";

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = $host;
$mail->Username = $username;
$mail->Password = $password;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->From = 'maised0707@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Başvuru Formu';
$mail->Subject = "$AdSoyad";
$mail->AddAddress($username,'Semih deneme');
$mail->AddAttachment($klasor.'/'.$adi,"Başvuru Formu".$uzanti);
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
if($mail->Send()){
echo "Başvuru Formunuz gönderilmiştir.";
}
else
{
echo "Başvuru formu gönderilemedi. Hata". $mail->ErrorInfo();
}
unlink($klasor.'/'.$adi);
}
?>
```

Comment: You're suppose to require the phpmailer autoloader, not `PHPMailer` and `SMTP.php`

Comment: It is in older version now there isn’t exist that file.

Comment: What's the version number? I have been using phpmailer since 2013 and I believe it always had a autoloader.

Comment: Okay I fixed the problem. I included the exception.php file to code. But now I have another problem. “Call to undefined method PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer::ErrorInfo()”

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. ErrorInfo is not a method. You should write ErrorInfo;